# how to lock notification screen in Samsung duos

Tags: notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

how to lock notification screen in Samsung duos to prevent access for quick toggles like Wi-Fi, GPS,Screen rotation, Screen brightness?

Answer (score 0):

That simply is absurd. You will have to lock your screen(Device lockscreen) to prevent anyone from accessing your phone's system controls. You simply cannot or wouldn't want to lock the "notifications" while using your device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason raised this question is, kids gets access to notification after unlock, they will increase the brightness of the screen(unknowingly) which really has high resolution and it impacts their eyes while watching kids videos. Even though the parent care is there this can not be avoidable.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way around this would be to set a pin/pattern lock to your device.